# How to controll number of rows in section in tableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How can I set number Of rows in section in `SUBCLASS` of `UITableView` (not in view controller)?
is there a function , say, `[self setNumberOfRowInSection:]`  or something like this?

---

I know about delegate method
- (int)tableView:numberOfRowsInSection;

BUT I'AM NOT IN VIEW CONTROLLER!
A made a class, wich is subclass of UITableView, and in some action, a want to SET (not to GET)
number of rows for section.

Comment: you can use delegate methods to determine number of rows in each section

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}
```

this will create 5 rows in section so you can write whatever your desired output is if from array then write [myArray count]; instead of 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Delegate`& `DataSource` method of `UITableView`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 10; //no. of row you want
}
```

Comment: The method has nothing to do with the table view's delegate.

Comment: @ Nikolai i just telling him to use delegte method or datasource method for any other thing to do

Comment: This question has nothing to do with "any other thing to do".